# i want to set animated background size and position on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the code I want to set my background size and position:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var header = $('body');

    //images
    var backgrounds = new Array(
        'url(image1)', 'url(image2)', 'url(image3)', 'url(image4)'
    );

    //animation
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        current++;
        current = current % backgrounds.length;
        header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    }
    setInterval(nextBackground, 7000);

    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);

});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What's your issue with setting the background size and position? You're already using the `css()` method? Also, if all images share the same settings, you could just set those rules in a stylesheet, not through JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want animation so in that case you should use random function:

The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range. The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user.

Note that as numbers in JavaScript are IEEE 754 floating point numbers with round-to-nearest-even behavior, the ranges claimed for the functions below (excluding the one for Math.random() itself) aren't exact. If extremely large bounds are chosen (253 or higher), it's possible in extremely rare cases to calculate the usually-excluded upper bound.

```
// Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

And your code should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var header = $('body');

    //images
    var backgrounds = new Array(
        'url(image1)', 'url(image2)', 'url(image3)', 'url(image4)'
    );

    //animation
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        current++;
        //current = current % backgrounds.length;
        current = getRandomArbitrary(0,backgrounds.length;
        header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    }
    setInterval(nextBackground, 7000);

    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);

});
```

and as per your method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var header = $('body');

    //images
    var backgrounds = new Array(
        'url(image1)', 'url(image2)', 'url(image3)', 'url(image4)'
    );

    //animation
    var current = 0;    

    function nextBackground() {
    if(current>=backgrounds.length)
    current = 0;              
        header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
        current++;  
    }
    setInterval(nextBackground, 7000);

    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);

});
```